# CarPlay long-press on fast forward/backward button on the steering wheel does not work

Tags: ios, swift, avplayerviewcontroller, carplay

When I use default `AVPlayerViewController`s setting `updatesNowPlayingInfoCenter` (https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avkit/avplayerviewcontroller/1845194-updatesnowplayinginfocenter)

`fastForward` and `fastBackward` works fine. The audio is „scrubbing” forward and backward with its characteristic sound.

The problem is that it causes NowPlaying is updated multiple times; by `AVPlayerViewControler` and by my custom code. In CarPlay this causes artwork to flicker or `AVQueuePlayer` to report wrong current time on looped `AVPlayerItem`, etc. (some other issues as well)

When I turn off `updatesNowPlayingInfoCenter` updates, only my code changes NowPlaying and everything works perfectly except long-press on fast forward and backward.

I tried with implementing `skipForwardCommand` and `skipBackwardCommand` (also with `seekForwardCommand` and `seekBackwardCommand`), but I’m unable to implement this nice scrubbing audio effect. Only X seconds seek when I press and plus another X seconds when button is released.

Can you please help me with a better implementation?

Comment: But all of your remote command handlers are called, right? Maybe try whether the `changePlaybackPositionCommand` is called multiple times when keeping your button pressed.

Comment: Only `seekForwardCommand` and `seekBackwardCommand` are called.

I’m experimenting now with scrubbing effect is it some mix of rate and small seek interval, etc.